# Excel VBA generating a set of 30 invoices with different

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple question. I have an excel file with an invoice format being linked to around 30 odd invoice details from a table in a different sheet. I have already devised a macro to save each iteration as a separate excel file. But i want the 'filename' to be automated. For eg, if i select to print invoices for records 1-15, filenames should be saved as 1,2,3 and so on. The existing code is as follows -

```
Sub PrintForms()
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer
Dim Msg As String
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Invoice").Activate
StartRow = Range("StartRow")
EndRow = Range("EndRow")

If StartRow > EndRow Then
    Msg = "ERROR" & vbCrLf & "The starting row must be less than the ending row!"
    MsgBox Msg, vbCritical, APPNAME
End If

For i = StartRow To EndRow
    Range("rowindex") = i
    If Range("Preview") Then
            Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = Workbooks.Add
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
            wb.SaveAs "C:\workspace\1. Sem-1 Accounts\macrotest1.xlsx"
    Else
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub EditData()
Worksheets("Invoice Format").Activate
Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub ReturnToForm()
Worksheets("Invoice").Activate
Range("rowindex").Select
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: `wb.SaveAs "C:\workspace\1. Sem-1 Accounts\macrotest1" & i & ".xlsx"` ought to do the trick.